# Not null endomorphism such that Ker f contained in im f?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can you suggest me (if it's possible) an example of a not null endomorphism such that Ker f is contained in im f?
Thanks in advice

Comment: $\operatorname{im} T \subseteq \ker T$ iff $T^20$. Is there a similar characterization of when $\ker T \subseteq \operatorname{im} T $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative map in polynomial spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Identity should do the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

Every invertible operator this will be trivially true as $ker f=0$ in that case.